# Maven and emma plugin

Tags: maven, osgi, emma

How to configure maven build to fail if some of bundles to instrument are misspelled or no target/coverage/coverage.xml file report is generated?

Answer (score 0):

I did not check, try:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-verifier-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <verificationFile>target/coverage/coverage.xml</verificationFile>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>main</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```